# Android Studio 3.5.3 show Design view empty but build is Successful

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

newbie in Android studio. Using Android Studio 3.5.3 to create app and the Build is Successful

I have the default MainActivity and activity_main.xml

Problem: 
when I clicked on the activity_main.xml
- The Design view empty. Thus I can not drag UI like Plain text or others onto the  Design activity Layout

Made changes in Style.xml

- added the Base in below:
  1) style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

  but this does not work.

Need your help to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MikeBottle, There might be a couple of things going on here. It could be because your activity doesn't have theme assigned. 
Please check this:
[image]

Note: In the design view, when you click the `eye` icon, it will give you the options to `show` / `hide` the layout decorations. It includes the top and bottom status bars. Please check if that changes anything.

Also, make sure the activity has theme assigned.

[image]

For the reference, I also included the layout preview to demonstrate how it look when `show layout decorations` is not checked.

Comment: 1) I removed Base from parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" and  2) Follow your instruction.  I got  a) Grey out layout b) this error msg: Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.  for Android studio 3.5.3 ,Do I need to add this in build.Gradle in dependency: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

Comment: @MilkBottle If you are not using `AppCompat` theme, you don't need to add the dependency. Please add `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorSecondary</item>
  </style>` in styles, add the dependency, and add `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` to MainActivity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. If it doesn't work, please provide your code in the question.

Comment: yes, click the eye icon and select show layout decoration.